# Trying to install MySQL on Centos 6.7, dependencies issue

Tags: centos, mysql, dependencies

I'm having problems installing MySQL in a Centos 6.7 (final). But suddenly I'm having this problem, something related to dependencies which I couldn't find any precise post to handle this issue , or maybe I just don't understand enough.

I ran the command: `yum install MySQL`

Then I got these errors:

[image: screenshot]

How exactly should I proceed with this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You installed a mysql-community repository for EL7, but you have EL6. Remove it and install the correct repository.

Comment: Thank you, but how do I remove it? Do I use --purge?

Comment: edit /etc/yum.d files

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can choose to install [Percona Server](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/installation/yum_repo.html). It works more properly.